# faceDistortionPack is not completely downloading from the library file

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

In Spark Ar it should be 14 or 15 Blend shapes in the faceDistortionPack but it doesn't work, it just downloaded 1 Blend shape - eye-scale.

How can I completely download this pack to work in this application?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgYZk.png)

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I've got the same problem